# Как добавить элемент в массив структур?

Tags: golang, struct

```
type SetNews struct {
    Arr []SimpleNews
}
type SimpleNews struct{
    Link string
    Header string
    Description string
}
one_news := SimpleNews{
    Link: "",
    Header: "",
    Description: "",
}
t := append(myNews.Arr, one_news)
fmt.Println(len(t))
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом добавить структуру в массив структур? Вот так не получается..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка в этой строчке:

```
t := append(myNews.Arr, one_news)
```

Должно быть так:

```
myNews.Arr = append(myNews.Arr, one_news)
```

Comment: Подчеркивает всю строку и пишет: evaluated but not used